# Check if grid is being filtered by object

Tags: filter, devexpress, xtragrid

I have placed radiobuttons above an `XtraGrid` in a WinForm and apply a filter to a particular column when the user clicks a particular button. I need to keep the buttons in sync with the filter even if the user manipulates the filter manually.

I can catch the `ColumnFilterChanged` event, but I don't know how to check whether a particular object is included in the user-created `ColumnFilterInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `gridView.RowFilter` in that event and get all the data from the string.

It might not be pretty but it works...